# launchd NetworkState when no network connection

Tags: macos, plist, launchd, keep-alive, network-state

Anyone familiar with `launchd` on Mac OS X, specifically the `NetworkState` (`bool`) key in `KeepAlive` section of a `.plist` file?

From the `man` pages, `launchd` should call an executable when there is no network connectivity on the Mac, when the plist is configured like this:

```
...
<key>KeepAlive</key>
<dict>
    <key>NetworkState</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
...
```

This seems to work okay, However, once a valid network connection is established (defined as the Mac having at least one non-loopback IPv4/6 address), `launchd` *should* stop calling the executable (because the `NetworkState` flag should prevent it).

The behavior I am seeing, though, is that `launchd` keeps calling my program *regardless* of the Mac's network connectivity! It’s as if `launchd` is completely ignoring the `NetworkState` flag.

Does anyone know how to make this work so that `launchd` will only call a program when there’s no network connection, and **stop** calling it once a network connection is established?

Comment: Really? Nothing? Tumbleweed? Isn't anyone else trying to do something like this?

Comment: You're not alone here. I've been playing around with this as well and haven't been able to get it to work as expected. There doesn't seem to be a lot out there on this, but depending on what you're looking to do, check out (http://tech.inhelsinki.nl/locationchanger/). That plist watches a directory to detect network changes. There may be help in there.

Comment: I created a plist for connecting to my wifi every ten seconds if NetworkState was false, as my Mac looses connection every night, but even when it reconnected and I assume NetworkState is true, it still kept reconnecting every ten seconds making the internet unusable. it didn't work as I thought it would.

Answer (score 6):

I've been trying to tackle this same problem for a while, and today I finally realized my misunderstanding.

When any of KeepAlive's conditions evaluate to true, that means "ensure this process is running."  When none of them evaluate to true, that means "*do not* ensure this process is running," not, as I had hoped, "ensure this process is *not* running."